# Adjectives with "-ing" and "-ed" and Present Simple

Tags: grammar, present-tense

I'm wondering if it's correct to use Adjectives ending with "ing" or "ed" in Present Simple.

For example:

- She is stunning.
- He is boring.
- The Earth is amazing.
- I am always depressed.

Is it Present Simple? Or not?

Comment: Would this question fit better on our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: @OldBunny2800 I'm new here. Didn't know about "English Language Learners" forum. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: She is = present simple "She is bored" (She is not interested in something; she feels bored)  "She is boring" (She is not an interesting person to talk to) *Bored* and *boring* are both adjectives, but they are not interchangeable. I think *this* is what the OP is asking about. Please confirm if my guess is correct.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, no I know the difference between Bored and Boring. I asked if it's Present Simple or some another tense, like Present Continuous.

Comment: How can "She is boring" be present continuous? Unless you're suggesting that the subject (she) is "boring" a hole in the ground, or she is repeatedly hitting someone over the head with a heavy blunt instrument and "[**stun](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stun)ning**" that poor person. The words "boring" and "stunning" are used as *adjectives* in your examples. The verb "to [**bore**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bore)" means something quite different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is correct to use adjectives formed from present participles (*verb*+ing) with the present simple tense as you've demonstrated.

> She is stunning.

It is also correct to add "to be" as you have.

> She is to be stunning.

The difference is the latter indicates futurity.  When you add "to be," you are no longer saying that she is presently stunning.  Instead, you are saying that she will be stunning or that it is expected that she will be stunning.

Comment: Hi, Benjamin, I think the OP is asking if *present participle* or *past participle* form could be used as an adjective. It doesn't seem to have anything to do with *to be*. And his question is whether the sentences are in the present simple tense.

Comment: @Rathony, didn't Benjamin answer that?. "It is correct to use adjectives with the present simple tense as you've demonstrated."

Comment: @Maksim In a way, yes. But "to be" is not in your question. Also, the post is not mentioning any past participle form. I am just pointing  out these two points.

Comment: I agree with Rathony...the post needs some fixin'.

Comment: @Rathony : This is a situation where another user's edit so changed the OP's question that the answer given before the edit no longer seems to be what the OP was asking.  The OP's question asked, "Is it correct? Or 'to be' + 'ing' always means present continuous?"  It did ask about "to be"+"ing," which is why I answered the way I did.  Maskim changed that part of the question to read, "Is it present simple?  Or not?"  That, however, is not what the OP asked.

Comment: @Rathony : I only mention this because you said, "But 'to be' is not in your question. Also, the post is not mentioning any past participle form."  --"To be" was in the OP's original question.  Both of these discrepancies you point out result from Maskim's edit after I had posted my response.  The OP's original question didn't ask about the past participle form, so I didn't include it, for doing so would have been off-topic.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman I see. We can't always check whether the question was edited and when it was done. Anyway, this is also one of the cases we discussed last time. The OP has the right to change his post and if your answer looks like it is not answering the question, you could receive a downvote or comment. Why not edit it? Not many users take a look at comments or previous (before-edit) question before casting downvote or making a comment. as I did. :-)

Comment: I edited my post to clarify my question. The answer is correct, everything's alright. No need to fight here :-)